# Why does GetUserAsync in EF Core return null when already sign in?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Why does `GetUserAsync` return null ?

```
var currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
```

Error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> lambda_method178(Closure )
>
> InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query parameter expression. See the inner exception for more information. To show additional information call 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging'.
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.ParameterExtractingExpressionVisitor.GetValue(Expression expression, out string parameterName)
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown while attempting to evaluate a LINQ query parameter expression. See the inner exception for more information. To show additional information call 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging'.
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> at lambda_method178(Closure )

Comment: Because the user doesn't exist?

Comment: Well it is more like: because login was on different branches. So Should log out and login again.